# How to close browser after form has been submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to submit a form and then the browser has to close. But I cannot understand why it will not work. For some reason, it will close the window, but it does not submit the form.

```
$('.cancel-confirm').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
    alert('Submitted - your window will now close');
    window.close();
});
```

```
<form asp-action="CancelActivity" method="post" class="absolute ff f-36 foreground-white" style="right:5em; top:20%;">
    <input type="hidden" name="ActivityID" value="@item.Activityid" />
    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="@(item.IsCancelled == true ? "false" : "true")" />
    <button class="btn ff f-22 background-transparant foreground-black cancel-confirm" type="submit"> @(item.IsCancelled == true ? "Genaktiver" : "Deaktiver") </button>
</form>
```

Tried to submit the form with jQuery and then close the window

Comment: Thanks for replying. It is closing the window, but it does not submit form

Comment: `alert` really messes up the order of your code.

Comment: I tried with and without but still doesn't submit form for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using jQuery, you can use ajax

```
$('.cancel-confirm').on('click', function () {
    $.post( "yourprocessor.php", { name: "Your Name", sex: "Male" })
      .done(function( data ) {
        alert('Submitted - your window will now close');
        window.close();
      });    
});
```

then process your submitted form.

Answer (score 1):

try to put an ID in your form,

```
$('#form-id').submit(function () {
    window.close();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. It does the closing, but it doesn't submit the form before closing

Comment: Try to use ajax request, then after it's done, add window.close(), `success:()=>window.close()`